# how can we install Aria Maestosa on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: software-installation, editor, midi

Previously, i just loved using Aria Maestosa, the very best midi editor i tried (i guess there are no comparable alternatives around, it’s a really amazing one), that i could install very easily then.

Now i’m struggling a lot installing it. How can we have it installed now, as easily?

Answer (score 2):

to add the repositiry open a terminal and

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
```

then setup keyring

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

then install the ariamaestosa

```
sudo apt install ariamaestosa
```

Comment: doesn’t work...

Comment: What error you are getting actually ??

Comment: >> wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: >> guest@macbookair:~$ sudo apt install ariamaestosa
E: Unable to locate package ariamaestosa

Comment: and when i found these .deb files and install them on gDebI, the library dependency packages asked are way too outdated, like libwxbase2.8-0, which is not at the repository anymore - i actually had libwxbase3.0 installed (the only available from the repository) and it keep asking for 2.8-0

Comment: perhaps you’re still using a very outdated version of Ubuntu?

Comment: follow [this](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-team/+archive/ubuntu/ariamaestosa)

Comment: i were trying it as well in the same time, also unsuccessfully - see that the packages there are from 5 years ago - and what we find on the sourceforge Aria Maestosa webpage, their last release was from 2017 (around 1 year and half ago)

Comment: i'm seeing that i might need to compile it from the source code, i wanted to avoid it - i was also looking for .rpm packages, and convert them to .deb or tarball somehow

Comment: All the packages of it are from 2014. If you really want it, then you can compile with source codes

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to build Aria under Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Download source code (this link is given in the Aria home page):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ariamaestosa/files/

2. Unzip the .bz2 file with command: `tar xjf`
3. The building instructions are given here:

http://ariamaestosa.sourceforge.net/building.html

## Note:

In my first attempt, compile failed due to a missing `libwxgtk2u-webview` library.  If this is the case, edit the file `SConstruct` in the top directory, find the line:

`env.ParseConfig( [WXCONFIG] + ['--cppflags','--libs','core,base,adv,net,webview'])`

and remove the last `webview` entry.  Then run the install script again.  It seems that this library is not needed.

Good luck!

Comment: Does pressing Up on a note cause the focus to shift to the zoom quantity above? It does for me and it ruins my workflow so I can't use it.